# Generating Function for weird Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, fibonacci-numbers

I couldn't solve the following excercise from my course of Differential Equations. The question is to find a power series solution for the differential equation:
\begin{equation} 
y''=y'+y, y(0)=0, y'(0)=1  \text{ of the form: } y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_n}{n!}x^n
\end{equation}

With $F_n$ the n-th number in the sequence of Fibonacci.

I was able to write this power series with a recursive relation:
\begin{equation}
(n)(n-1)a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+a_n \text{ or }a_n=\frac{a_{n-1}}{n}+\frac{a_n}{n(n-1)}
\end{equation}

I did try to write $a_{n-1}$ as the sum of his antecedents, which gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{2a_{n-2}(n-2)+a_{n-3}}{n(n-1)(n-2)}
\end{equation}
Continuation does indeed bring the Fibonacci series, since:
\begin{equation}
F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}=2\cdot F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}
\end{equation}
And continuing of the recursive relation all the way would give the same result as $F_n/n!$ since the factor $(n-2)$ would become one , but how would I go about proving this more accurately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with your (corrected)
$(n)(n-1)a_n=(n-1)a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}
$
for
$y(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n
$.
Multiplying by
$(n-2)!$ gives
$n!a_n=(n-1)!a_{n-1}+(n-2)!a_{n-2}
$.
Finally,
setting
$n!a_n = b_n$
gives
$b_n = b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}
$,
the Fibonacci recurrence.

If $y(0) = 0$
then
$a_0 = 0$
so $b_0 = 0$.

If $y'(0) = 1$
then
$a_1 = 1$
so $b_1 = 1$
so that
$b_n = F_n$
(with $F_{0..3} = 0, 1, 1, 2$)
and
$a_n
=\dfrac{b_n}{n!}
=\dfrac{F_n}{n!}
$.

Note that we need to have
$y'(0)$
specified.